# Why can't I use method that is not defined in interface?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I have an interface and three classes.  In class `B`, I define a method called `printHello`.  Then, in class `Test`, I declare a new `IHello` object and assign it to a new B.

The problem is, the code does not compile, because I get an error indicating "The method printHello() is undefined for type IHello".  This is confusing to me, because I am able to assign an object of type `IHello` to a new `B`, so shouldn't that object be able to use `B`'s methods even if the interface does not have them?

To solve this problem, I understand I could either declare a method called `printHello` in the `IHello` interface, or I could declare the object of type B instead.  Is there anything else I could do to solve the problem?

Interface IHello

```
public interface IHello {

    void hello();

}
```

Class A

```
public class A implements IHello{

    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Class B

```
public class B extends A  {

        public void printHello(){
            this.hello();
        }
}
```

Class Test

```
public class Test {

    public static IHello b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        b = new B();
        b.printHello(); //The method printHello() is undefined for type IHello
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the *type* of the ***variable*** (not the *object*)? This is what the compiler sees.  This has been asked here a gazillion times by the way.

Comment: The type of the variable is IHello, but since its assigned to a `B`, I am trying to understand why I can't use the methods of `B`.

Comment: The compiler is not looking at the actual object type. It's looking at the type you declared - IHello. In some cases, the compiler might not *know* the actual object type, because that might be available only at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class B extends Class A, and none of your Class A or B has relationship with Interface IHello, therefore  you cannot instantiate B  and assign it to `b` because the type of `b` is `IHello`

If your Class A is an implementation of Interface `IHello`, you should make it as

```
public class A implements IHello{
    ...
}
```

Be aware that if you declare instance variable x as type XXX, only the methods in class XXX is visible to instance x. In your case, you declare b as IHello, only method hello() is accessible by instance b, it cannot access `printHello()`, only instance declared as `B` can invoke `printHello()`, if you are 100% sure b is an instance of B, you can cast instance b to type B.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but even with that change I still get the same error.

Comment: @OmarN see my last sentence